# Use multiple include and then include in EF query C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, linq

I tried this code:

```
 var result = _repository.Entity
                         .Include(x => x.table1)
                         .Include(x => x.table2).ThenInclude(x => x.table3).ThenInclude(x => x.table4)
                         .Where(x => x.table1.Id == 10)
```

I want to achieve like below which is not working:

```
var result = _repository.Entity
                         .Include(x => x.table1).select(new table1{..})
                         .Include(x => x.table2).ThenInclude(x => x.table3).ThenInclude(x => x.table4)
                         .Where(x => x.table1.Id == 10)
```

In this query, I want to use select on table1 i.e. to select on few columns say id, name.

I am trying but I use select right after the `.Include(x => x.table1).select(....)`  then I am unable to use `.Include` for other tables.

I am not sure how to achieve this with join conditions; I tried but not able to achieve this, a small idea to resolve this will be helpful to proceed further.

Comment: Select after the Where clause?

Comment: You can't include just some properties of a related entity. If you want to pick and choose the parts of the entities you want to keep then you need to create new types with just those properties and then map to those types as the last step in the query.

Comment: @C1sc0 i want to select right after the include reason why to include whole table1 object once we have select option..otherwise DTO class is another option which i can use but i want to use after include..please guide if you have any idea thanks

Comment: If you use select Include is ignored. You can either use `Include` and return entire entities, or use `Select` and return selected properties. These properties can also be navigation properties, like `Select(x => new { x.Table1Property, x.Table2, x.Table2.Table3, ... }`.